# Vacuum polarization or electron with structure?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, potential, quantum-electrodynamics

Is it possible to construct some charge density $ρ(r)$ to get the Uehling-Potential?
$${\displaystyle V_{\text{Uehling}}(r)\approx -Z\alpha \hbar c{\frac {1}{r}}\left(1+{\frac {\alpha }{8\pi ^{2}{\sqrt {2}}}}\left({\frac {\lambda }{r}}\right)^{3/2}e^{-4\pi {\frac {r}{\lambda }}}\right)+{\mathcal {O}}(\alpha ^{3})}$$

The electric potential of a continuous charge distribution $ρ(r)$ is

$${\displaystyle V_{\mathbf {E} }(\mathbf {r} )={\frac {1}{4\pi \varepsilon _{0}}}\int {\frac {\rho (\mathbf {r} ')}{|\mathbf {r} -\mathbf {r} '|}}d^{3}r'.}$$

So interpreting the difference from the Coulomb potential not as vacuum polarization, but as some structure in the electron?

Answer (score 0):

The entire theory (quantum electrodynamics) used by Uehling to *derive* this potential, is based on the assumption that the electron is a *point* particle. So the mainstream interpretation of the extra charge density “outside” the electron is that it is polarization of the vacuum by the point electron. Any other conclusion contradicts the premises of the theory.

Comment: ok but I mean - with different assumptions one can derive equal results

Comment: No, because you would have to start with a totally different QFT based on charged particles with finite extent. (I don’t know if such a theory is even mathematically renormalizable.) Such a particle would polarize the vacuum *differently* than a point particle does. And there would be no justification for starting with any particular charge density distribution.

Comment: I mean in general: 'with different assumptions one can derive equal results'. Why do we have to start with a totally different QFT - when do we say we are dealing with pointlike particles? But actually - I was looking for something like this: The zeeman effect can be explained classically or with QMechanics. I was wondering if the uehling term could be derived without QFT

Comment: *I was wondering if the uehling term could be derived without QFT.* Not as far as I know.

Comment: Ok then lets do it together